# Return all nodes and their relationships iff node has more than 1 relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm all new to writing cypher.

I'm trying to do a query that returns the nodes in my database that are related to two nodes or more.

Hope it makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: Even a "leaf" node can be related to 2 or more nodes (depending on how you wish to define the concept of "leaf"). Can you make your question more explicit?

Comment: I can try. 

If a node has a relation with two or more nodes I want to return the node and its relations. If it is related to one or zero nodes I do not want it. 

Does it make better sense? Not exactly sure how I can make it more explicit.

Comment: I've adjusted the subject to match your comment.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

1.
This will return each node that has more than 1 relationship, along with its relationships:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WITH n, COLLECT(r) AS rs
WHERE SIZE(rs) > 1
RETURN n, rs
```

2.
This will return each node that has relationships to more than 1 node, along with its relationships:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
WITH n, COLLECT(r) AS rs, COUNT(DISTINCT m) AS mCount
WHERE mCount > 1
RETURN n, rs
```

Comment: Thanks! It's almost what I'm looking for. The query returns all nodes and their relationships iff node has more than 1 relationship. Thing is that in my db a node A can have more than 1 relationship to another node B. What I'm looking for is therefore a query that returns all nodes and their relationships iff node has a relationship to more than 1 node. So A related to B and A related C should return A. A related to B with more than 1 relationship should not return A. Does it make sense?